# Некорректно работает программа. Кортеж во множестве. Питон

Tags: python, множества

```
#Пользователь вводит необходимое число кортежей в множестве (кортежи состоят из нечётных чисел)
dlin = int(input())
mn = set()

for i in range(dlin*2):
    if i % 2 != 0:
        mn.add((i, i+2))
print(mn)
```

Почему данная программа выводит кортежи в множестве в хаотичном порядке
числа в котрежах правильные

Comment: Потому что `set` в Питоне хранит свои элементы в произвольном порядке. Вы на этот порядок влиять не можете.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ

Comment: Если вам нужно упорядоченное множество - используйте ключи словаря, в качестве значений можете использовать что угодно. Словари в питоне начиная с какой-то версии (кажется 3.6) сохраняют порядок добавления элементов.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Почему данная программа выводит кортежи в множестве в хаотичном порядке числа в котрежах правильные

Потому что *set* **неупорядоченная коллекция**.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ

Comment: Пожалуйста, обращайтесь.